# How to query this XML document in C#.NET 3.5

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an XML document of the form:

```
<metadata>
      <item name="Name" type="xs:string" length="102"/>
      <item name="Email" type="xs:string" length="202"/>
</metadata>
<data>
    <row>
        <value>Daniel</value>
        <value>daniel@no-reply.com</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <value>George</value>
        <value>george@no-reply.com</value>             
    </row>
</data>
```

The ordering and number of columns may change so it is not sufficient to assume //row/value[1]/text() always holds 'Name'.

What is the best way to query the document using the metadata names to pull the right values?

I am querying the document in C#.NET3.5 so can use XDocument, XPath etc... whichever is the best for the job.

Comment: This is **NOT** a valid, well-formed XML document - the first ground rule is: one and only one root element - you don't have that here....

Comment: It does have a root element  - I just neglected to add it into the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would transform this input (is it plist?) into a "real" XML document where the tags have better names (i.e. the metadata description). You can achieve this by using xsl transformation and a selfwritten stylesheet (can assist if needed).

After that, you would have a structure like:

```
<data>
  <row>
    <Name>Daniel</Name>
    <Email>daniel@no-reply.com</Email>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Name>George</Name>
    <Email>george@no-reply.com</Email>
  </row>
</data>
```

Now then it's easy to address the nodes using `/data/row/Name` and selecting them with an [XPathNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx)

Comment: It's coming out of a Cognos reporting engine and I have no control over the format. That might be the way forward but I would still need to understand how to query to original document in XSL. I'll explore this option further.

Comment: I'll provide a stylesheet after I got home (in about an hour) ;)

Comment: I have had a first go at a stylesheet (see answer to my own question). It appears to work with some test data. Is this intermediary stylesheet the best way to approach it?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best way, but it's a way and easy to maintain. It would be also possible to deal with the metadata mapping in code (XmlReader, XmlDocument, etc), but I find it easier this way.

Answer (score 1):

This intermeidary stylesheet is my attempt in response to Scoregraphic's suggestion (I posted as an answer for readability):

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<data>
    <xsl:for-each select="/doc/data/row">
    <row>
        <xsl:for-each select="./value">
        <xsl:variable name="cur" select='position()' />
        <xsl:element name="{/doc/metadata/item[$cur]/@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </row>
    </xsl:for-each>
</data>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: After a first look, this should work fine. Please check all the possible metadata-output tags, so you don't write illegal XML characters (in your example, this is no problem). I think of chars like &, <, >, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what you're doing, just a nice place to start

```
<cars xmlns="/carsSchema.xsd">
  <car age="5">
    <carId>1</carId>
    <brand>BMW</brand>
    <model>320i</model>
    <color paintType="metallic">Red</color>
  </car>

  <car age="2">
    <carId>2</carId>
    <brand>VW</brand>
    <model>Golf</model>
    <color paintType="matt">White</color>
  </car>
[...]
</cars>


XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(currentDir + "\\Cars.xml");
XNamespace ns = "/carSchema.xsd";

var carInfo1 = from car in xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "car")
                   select (string)car.Element(ns + "brand") + ": " + 
                          (string)car.Element(ns + "model");
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess: you're retrieving a xml-formatted cognos report?

I'm just about to deal with the same problem but i think cognos supports defining a schema for your report result, so you won't have to xsl-transform it.

...

I rummaged around a bit and found the following url parameter options in the offical cognos viewer documentation:

run.xslURL - Specifies the location of a XSL-stylesheet to apply to the report. Value for this param is a valid URI.

I did not try this yet, but i will need to transform a report result just like you.

Comment: Yes but it's the web API integrated into a SaaS product and I cannot see any way of configuring the output (not even the Excel output)

Comment: It would be handy if I could do that with the above transform but I only have access to a very basic web-based query studio with no option to specify this.

Comment: I use the same principle but perform the transfom outside of cognos

Comment: I went to transform outside cognos too - your xsl sample was very useful +1.